# single web test for 3 diff roles

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2010, webtest

I have created a web test in vs2010. which browse through the products.
I have 3 roles in my site guest (non logged in ), logged in not verified, logged in verified.

How I can use single test for all 3 roles?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a representative web test for each role as different roles will take different actions within your site. Having webtests for each role will allow you to 
control the ratios of each user within any load testing you do based on those webtests.